# Preferences DataStore in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-jetpack, datastore

I'm working on a Java based Android Project where I'm using sharedPreferences to store the data.

I want to use Preferences DataStore in my project but unable to find any good example to take reference. Please suggest any reference examples in Java to implement preference data store in Android or how to migrate from shared prefs to DataStore.

I tried to go through [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore?gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=Cj0KCQjwp86EBhD7ARIsAFkgakg-4Xc0UsX_xgNZmeSeNdZfTuoMoZ4JPUuZUyJq7dUOAV_JSY029GoaAgCHEALw_wcB#java), but couldn't understand the example provided

Answer (score 2):

I was at the exact same point in my project. Suddenly the sharedpreferences are deprecated, so what now.
DataStore can be found rather quickly but I also think the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-datastore) is not sufficient in clearing up what needs to be done.

I did get it to work though:

**1. Implementing**

Implement this in the dependencies (app module):

```
//DataStore instead of SharedPreferences
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"
//RxJava2 support
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-rxjava2:1.0.0"
```

**2. Initializing**

I am using the RxDataStore and the associated RxDataStoreBuilder:

```
RxDataStore<Preferences> dataStoreRX; //Top Part
dataStoreRX = new RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder(this,"your_datastorename").build(); //onCreate
```

**3. Storing Data**

To save data in the DataStore you can use what is in the doc:

```
public boolean putStringValue(String Key, String value){
  boolean returnvalue;
  Preferences.Key<String> PREF_KEY = PreferencesKeys.stringKey(Key);
  Single<Preferences> updateResult =  dataStoreRX.updateDataAsync(prefsIn -> {
  MutablePreferences mutablePreferences = prefsIn.toMutablePreferences();
  mutablePreferences.set(PREF_KEY, value);
  return Single.just(mutablePreferences);
  }).onErrorReturnItem(pref_error);

  returnvalue = updateResult.blockingGet() != pref_error;
  return returnvalue;
}
```

With the litte addition of error handling: onErrorReturnItem

```
Preferences pref_error = new Preferences() {...};
```

Doesnt matter whats in pref_error, it only exists to be returned and to check if it is returned.

**4. Retreiving Data**

To retreive, same thing but backwards and with error-handling:

```
String getStringValue(String Key) {
  Preferences.Key<String> PREF_KEY = PreferencesKeys.stringKey(Key);
  Single<String> value = dataStoreRX.data().firstOrError().map(prefs -> prefs.get(PREF_KEY)).onErrorReturnItem("null");
  return value.blockingGet();
}
```

**5. More than that!**

But there is way more to that. If you want to use the DataStore across several activities you need to use a Singleton and thore it as such. The reason is you cant create more than one instance of one DataStore. That is in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-datastore) but as I said, I think it is not complete.
Also error-handling is not described there.

But you can use all datatypes to store them with the correct KEY and with the respective returnvalue as an error.

I elaborate more on this and how to set up the Singleton here: [Link to Medium](https://medium.com/@deadmanapple/using-the-android-datastore-library-instead-of-sharedpreferences-in-java-d6744c348a05)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very straightforward to migrate from sharedPreferences to dataStore.
Pass the old SharedPref name and the migration happens automatically.

```
private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> =
    context.createDataStore(
        name = "data",
        migrations = 
          listOf(SharedPreferencesMigration(context, "shared_preferences_name"))
    )
```

Comment: Hi Narendra, thank you for sharing your thought, the answer you mentioned is in Kotlin but my project is in Java, is this the same process in Java too ?

Comment: Yes.> just the Syntax will be different .